# Access to the cookies of the default browser

Tags: python, browser, cookies

I want to write a program that opens the browser and open a url with a given cookie. I dont know how to do this. Maybe I could modify the cookies in the default place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'cookiename=cookievalue'))
f = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

Modules to look into:

[urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)
[cookielib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html) 
[Cookie](http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html)

Answer (score 2):

In python, you can emulate a browser with the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library. Also, there is good documentation about mechanize and cookies.